# Pyparsing grammar incorrect

Tags: parsing, pyparsing

Why does the following pyparsing grammar not parse the string correctly?

```
import pyparsing as pp

token_any = pp.Word(pp.printables)
comment = pp.Literal("*") + token_any("comment text") + "*"

res = comment.parse_string("""*asd*""")
print(res.dump())
```

The error is `Expected '*', found end of text  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)`. If I understand this correctly, the comment text matches to the end of the string. But shouldn't the next step in the parsing be to try to match the remaining part of the rule, backing up until it does? i.e. this should match the regex `\*.*\*` (excluding non-printable characters, which my input string doesn't have)

Comment: No, pyparsing is purely left-to-right, and does not do backtracking like regexen. You can get this to match if you define token_any as `token_any = pp.Word(pp.printables, exclude_chars="*")`.